# How to define variables that share the same ram area in avr studio 7?

Tags: atmega16

I need to host a 500 byte array momentarily for a block of a large program that consists of several blocks but I don't have enough ram so I want to share an area of ram between two blocks of the program. Obviously the execution of both blocks is exclusive.

The program written in C will run on atmega16 and written in avr studio 7.

How can I define the variables of each block so that the compiler assigns them the same ram area without generating an error?

Thank you.

I tried to define my own segment but that doesn't mean they share the same ram area.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the array inside a function, it tells the C compiler that the array will no longer be needed once returning from the function (so it will be stack allocated almost always, and the memory will be automatically freed once the function returned). Otherwise, the array might be statically allocated, which reserves the memory for the entire runtime.

If the array is already declared inside a function, there probably is no way to do what you want, since there is no space to store the rest of your program data for a temporary period, and trying to "trick" the compiler will only introduce potentially fatal bugs and undefined behavior.

You could always try to refactor your code so that the array's life is contained as early as possible in the call stack. Meaning that instead of creating the array after 10 function calls (without returning) you can try to create it , use it and then proceed to the rest of the calls, but this is an approach which requires some understanding of how C compilers work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different solutions, each with its ups and downs detailed out below. For the matter of discussion, I'll assume you have two modules with headers like `module1.h` which typedefs `module1_t`, and similar for `module2.h`.

| Approach | RAM Region | Complies to Standard | Costs extra Code for (De)Allocation | Costs extra RAM | Must know Size at Compile Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A. Local vars** | Stack | Yes | Yes (a bit) | No | No |
| **B. Union** | Static Storage | Yes | No | No | Yes |
| **C. use __heap_start** | — | No | No | No | No |
| **D. malloc** | Heap | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |
| **E. COMMON** | Static Storage | Legacy C | No | No | Yes |

### A. Use local Objects

Just use local objects in respective functions like in:

```cpp
#include "module1.h"

void run_module1 (void)
{
    // Enter / init module1.
    module1_t module1;

    // Execute module1.
    for (bool looping = true; looping; )
    {
        // Execute code of module1 until
        // I/O terminates its execution.
    }
    // Leave module1.
}
```

### B. Union holding required Components

The following solution uses a `union`:

```cpp
#include "module1.h"
#include "module2.h"

typedef union
{
    module1_t module1;
    module2_t module2;
} modules_t;

extern modules_t modules;

// Use modules.module1 in module1.c
```

and then use `modules.module1` in module 1 etc. You have to pick a module that defines the `modules` object, e.g. `modules_t modules;` in `module1.c`, but not in `module2.c`.

The drawback of this method is that you have to expose everything needed to define the `module*_t` objects, which might be quite annoying when you have many modules that participate in that "coalescing".

Advantage is that no code is needed to allocate or free the data as it lives in static storage.

### C. Locate the Objects by Hand in the Heap Region

The following solution uses the fact that the default `avr-gcc` linker script defines a symbol `__heap_start` which immediately follows the memory region used for static storage:

```cpp
#include "module1.h"

extern module1_t module1 __asm("__heap_start");

// Use module1
// Similar code in module2 etc.
```

The value of the symbol points one past the last location of objects in static storage (stuff in `.data`, `.bss`, `.noinit`).  The is *no need to define objects in C/C++ code*

You can have at most one group of objects "allocated" that way.

The memory starting at `__heap_start` is supposed used by `malloc`, hence this solution won't work together with `malloc`, which is the case for almost all AVR applicatons.

Upside is that no code is needed to allocate or free the object(s) because they all live in static storage.  Moreover, there is no need to expose all of `moduleN.h`; all can be done in `moduleN.c`.

Downside is that it's avr-gcc specific and not covered by the standard (assembly names by means of `asm` is a GCC extension, and `__heap_start` is specific to GNU tools for AVR).  Moreover, this bypasses tools that show memory consumption of static storage like `avr-size`.

### D. `malloc` and `free`

I am mentioning this one for completeness only.  In AVR programs you would always avoid `malloc` if possible (Which is the case here).  It consumes code and also RAM for administration.  Memory fragmentation is no issue, though, because at most one object is allocated at a time (assuming rest of the code avoids `malloc`).

### E. Common Section

Also just for completeness:

Some binary formats (aout?) support common symbols for tentative declarations in C. In each module, declare

```
module1_t module;
```

i.e. use the same name across modules and no initializer.  This requires the use of option [`-fcommon`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fcommon). GCC changed the default from `-fcommon` to `-fno-common` some time ago.  This might lead to hick-ups with LTO or linters.